# junit тест с Mockito и PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Нужно ли проверять вызов исключения путем замены локальной переменной File.

```
public class ClassA {

public void writeToFile(String filePathString) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File(filePathString);
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
        // do something
        }else throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Все равно тест проходит даже если менять значения переменной f.exists()

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassA.class)
public class ClassATest {

    ClassA classA;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        classA = new ClassA();
    }

    @Test
    public void writeToFile_throwExIfFileNotFound() throws Exception {
        File f = Mockito.mock(File.class);

        Mockito.when(f.exists())
                .thenReturn(true);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class)
                .withArguments(Mockito.anyString())
                .thenReturn(f);

        try{
            classA.writeToFile(Mockito.anyString());

        }catch (Exception ex){
            Assertions.assertThat(ex)
                    .isInstanceOf(FileNotFoundException.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Все равно тест проходит даже если менять значения переменной f.exists()

Вы же в данном тесте проверяете, что будет выброшено исключение, если файла нет?
В таком случае `f.exists()` должно вернуть `false` (либо `f.isDirectory() == true`) - вы же его устанавливаете в `true`:

```
Mockito.when(f.exists())
        .thenReturn(true);
```

**PS:** для проверки исключения проще указать в аннотации `@Test` ожидаемое исключение, и если оно не будет выброшено - тест будет считаться не пройденным:

```
@Test(expected=FileNotFoundException.class)
```